# Vue JS: Show number of results for each item in select drop-down menu

Tags: vue.js

I would like to display the number of each result available beside each result in a select drop-down menu.

I can get it to display all results in the data set using the code below but not the individual amounts. Im new to Vue, so not sure exactly how to proceed. Can anyone help, please?

```
  <select v-model="fee"
                    class="form-control"
                    @change="Feeonchange()"
                    :disabled="selectDisabledFees"
                  >
                    <option disabled value="">Select fee status</option>
                    <option v-for="fee in uniqueFees" :key="fee" :value="fee">
                      {{ fee }} ({{ resultFees }})
                    </option>
                  </select>



computed:
     resultFees() {
          const resultFeesCount = this.results.filter((results) => {
            return this.uniqueFees;
          });
          return resultFeesCount.length;
        },
```

Comment: What does uniqueFees contain?

Comment: Hello, this is the code for UniqueFees. So I think its 'result.metaData.x'. Is that what you mean?
 uniqueFees() {
      const metaxFees = (this.ClassCheck === true
        ? this.results
        : this.resultfilteredResults
      )
        .filter((result) => result.metaData && result.metaData.x)
        .map((item) => item.metaData.x)
        .filter((fee, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(fee) === i);
   
TBC

Comment: let fees = [];
      metaxFees.forEach((item) => {
        const splitArr = item.split(", ");
        fees = fees.concat(splitArr);
      });
      return fees.filter((fee, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(fee) === i);
    },

Thank you!

Comment: what to you mean by the number of each results?

Comment: Hi, I reposted this question as I didn't think I had made myself clear enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096221/vue-js-add-number-of-available-options-in-select-drop-down-menu