# Vue JS: Add number of available options in select drop down menu

Tags: vue.js

[image: Example]

I'm trying to display the number of options next to each item in a select drop-down menu. Like in the example.

My data is pulled from a JSON using AXIOS. Here is one line from an object in my array

```
"Data": {
      "K": "Part Time, Full-time",
    },
```

and the computed property which I'm attempting to create. It brings back a number but not the ones I would like. Can anyone help me out with this, please?

```
  computed: {
 feeCount() {
      const feeResults = this.results.filter(
        (result) => result.Data && result.Data.K
      );

      return feeResults.length;
    },
}
```

Comment: consider adding full vue files, thats not a secret ;-) Also i recommend to really analyze the API and what exactly is returned, bc u can not tell what exactly is returned, the logic seems to work. Try postman (tool for working with apis) to do this.

Comment: Call you post the full data from your axios call? Then I should be able to help with the computed property.

Comment: Hello, the JSON file is huge, so I cant share it. i have taken a sample though, which will hopefully allow you to see what's happening. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: "metaData": {
            "G": "",
            "H": "",
            "J": "",
            "K": "Part Time",       
          },         
        },
        {   
          "metaData": {
             "G": "",
            "H": "",
            "J": "",
            "K": "Full-time, Part Time",           
          },                  
        },
        {       
          "metaData": {            
            "G": "",
            "H": "",
            "J": "",
            "K": "Full-time, Part Time, Distance",               
          },          
        },

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `"Part Time, Full-time"` is a string, not an array, so you're getting the length of the string instead.

You can use `result.Data.K.split(',')` to generate an array then count the length from that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will give that a go. Thank you very much for your help.